# About the Bloch conjecture on entire curves

Tags: complex-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

The Bloch conjecture states the following:

**Bloch's conjecture.** Let $X$ be a compact complex Kähler variety such that the irregularity $q = h^0(X,\Omega^1_X)$ is larger than the dimension $n = \dim X$. Then, every entire curve drawn in $X$ is analytically degenerate.

Here $X$ may be singular and $\Omega^1_X$ can be defined in any reasonable way (direct
image of the $\Omega^1_{\widetilde X}$ of a desingularization $\widetilde X$ or direct image of $\Omega^1_U$ where $U$ is the set of regular points in the normalization of $X$).
By an entire curve I mean a non constant holomorphic map $f\colon\mathbb C\to X$, and analytically degenerate means that there exists a closed analytic subset $Y\subsetneq X$ such that $f(\mathbb C)\subset Y$.

This conjecture has been proven, thanks to the works of Ochiai, by Kawamata and, independently, by Wong.

A standard Albanese map argument permits to reduce the conjecture to the following statement:

*Let $A$ be an abelian variety and $f\colon\mathbb C\to A$ an entire curve. Then, the Zariski closure $\overline{f(\mathbb C)}$ is a translate of a subtorus.*

In particular a subvariety of an abelian variety does not have any entire curve (Brody hyperbolicity) if and only if it does not contain any translate of a subtorus. Thus, in a simple abelian variety every subvariety is hyperbolic. More generally, if a subvariety of an abelian variety is not a translate of a subtorus, then every entire curve in $X$ is analytically degenerate.

**Question 1.** Is there any geometric characterization or sufficient condition in order to insure that the Albanese variety of a projective algebraic manifold is simple?

**Question 2.** Is there any geometric characterization or sufficient condition, *other than having big irregularity*, in order to insure that the image of a projective algebraic manifold via the Albanese map is a proper subvariety?

Notice that by the universal property of the Albanese map, if the image of a projective algebraic manifold via the Albanese map is a proper subvariety then this image is necessarily not a translate of a subtorus.

**N.B.** I changed the last part of my post. Now, Question 2 is no more as in the previously, not reedited post. In particular the comment of ulrich refers to my previous Question 2.

Comment: What is an analytically degenerate curve?

Comment: I define this at line 7 from above.

Comment: A subvariety $X$ of abelian variety $A$ is of general type unless there is an abelian subvariety $B$ of $A$, translation by which preserves $X$; this is proved in Ueno's Springer Lecture Notes on classification theory, but I do not have the precise reference right now. If the abelian variety is not simple, then using products you can construct subvarieties with arbitrarily large irregularity but not of general type.

Comment: By "Abelian Variety", do you mean a complete, irreducible and reduced group scheme of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Ahahahahahahahahahahahah. Exactly!